# Проблема с on_message не реагирует на команды

Tags: python, discord.py

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

читал на документации discord.py вставил не помогло, видимо мозгов не хватает

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не реагирует на команды

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, убедитесь что боту установлен префикс, если нет то воспользуйтесь командой

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')
```

Во-вторых, если префикс установлен, то убедитесь правильность написание кода, c помощью простой команды

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

bot.run('token')
```

Если вы отправите команду `>ping` и бот вам ответить то, префикс работать исправно и у вас проблема в коде, если не ответить то убедитесь что префикс установлен вообще

Comment: Да все нормально потому что до этого все было нормально я написал и он перестал реагировать, я читал люди говорят это из за on_message

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Пропишите это в самом начале ивента on_message, так бот будет рассматривать сообщение сначала как команду, а уже потом как сообщение

Также стоит посмотреть есть ли у бота право читать сообщения и такое намерение (intents = discord.Intents.all(), при создании клиента бота)

Comment: Также стоит посмотреть есть ли у бота право читать сообщения и такое намерение (intents = discord.Intents.all(), при создании клиента бота)